# Extracting specific tag from XML in python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a metadata file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="uuid_id" version="2.0">
    <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
        <dc:title>Princeton Review Digital SAT Premium Prep, 2024: 4 Practice Tests + Online Flashcards + Review &amp; Tools</dc:title>
        <dc:creator opf:file-as="Princeton Review, The" opf:role="aut">The Princeton Review</dc:creator>
        <dc:identifier opf:scheme="ISBN">9780593516874</dc:identifier>
        <dc:identifier opf:scheme="AMAZON">0593516877</dc:identifier>
        <dc:identifier opf:scheme="GOODREADS">63139948</dc:identifier>
        <dc:identifier opf:scheme="GOOGLE">o6i4EAAAQBAJ</dc:identifier>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

I know how to use BeautifulSoup to extract fields like `<dc.title>`.  I'm struggling how to extract only the ISBN field (`<dc:identifier opf:scheme="ISBN">`).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ('metadata.opf', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

metadata = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')
title = metadata.find('dc:title')
print(title.text)

author = metadata.find('dc:creator')
print(author.text)

# isbn = metadata.find_all('dc:identifier'). # This finds 4 fields, as expected.
```

How do I limit it?  I can't depend on the order of the fields, and the ISBN length can vary.

Comment: `metadata.find('dc:identifier')` should just find the first one, which is the ISBN you are looking for since you are calling `find` and not `findAll` What is the issue? `metadata.find('dc:identifier').text` returns `'9780593516874'`

Comment: I do not know that ISBN will come first in every case, so I can't depend on that.  (I have a typo up there, it was find_all() that returns 4 fields.)

Comment: `[data for data in metadata.findAll('dc:identifier') if data['opf:scheme'] == 'ISBN']`

Comment: My knowledge of python is not great, and I'm unfamiliar with the bracket notation you used.  Is there a link to explain it?  Thanks!

Comment: It is [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) - i.e., a way to iterate over items and create a list without having to append to an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the find method has an argument attribute using it you should be able to select ISBN

```
isbn = metadata.find('dc:identifier', attrs={"opf:scheme": "ISBN"})
```

So the code could be written like

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ('metadata.opf', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

metadata = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')
title = metadata.find('dc:title')
print(title.text)

author = metadata.find('dc:creator')
print(author.text)

isbn = metadata.find('dc:identifier', attrs={"opf:scheme": "ISBN"}) # This finds 4 fields, as expected. 
print(isbn.text)
```

and should result in

```
Princeton Review Digital SAT Premium Prep, 2024: 4 Practice Tests + Online Flashcards + Review & Tools
The Princeton Review
9780593516874
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find